# A clock into StackExchange to access time counting

Tags: discussion, editing, community

Dear users I sent the following request to the Stack Overflow team who suggested I submit it to the website contact http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com. I sent on 12/30/16 but still have not had any response. Could anyone give me some advice?

*As a Italian teacher, in relation art.1, paragraph 124, of Law 107 of 2015 concerning teacher training, are obliged to have played a certain number of hours, to be diluted in the three-year duration of the training plan issued by the Ministry of Education University and Research. I ask if it is possible to improve the site, inserting a clock, indicating the duration of access weekly, monthly and yearly.*

---

Dear Werner,
I thank you for your very comprehensive detailed response and I apologize for the delay from bad internet network connection in my area. Unfortunately the pages are in Italian, and you insert the link of the 107/2015 law that relates to my professional training. If you enter a watch that would mark the time of access to the site is not possible, it would, at least for my teaching activities, useful to have a certificate generated by the site where you can detect my skills up to date on progress.

http://www.agendadigitale.eu/smart-cities-communities/la-formazione-docenti-e-non-solo-nel-piano-nazionale-scuola-digitale-tutto-cio-che-c-e-da_2781.htm

http://www.orizzontescuola.it/guida/formazione-docenti-nessun-monte-ore-obbligatorio-collegio-dei-docenti-e-libero-di-fissarlo/

http://www.oggiscuola.com/web/2016/12/20/formazione-nessun-limite-minimo-ore-cosa-sara-importante/

I will wait patiently your reply hoping that I can, oneday to have a document for my supplementary educational activities. The service offered by Stack Exchange are excellent from every point of view and I had the chance to know, albeit virtually, teachers / highly trained people like you.
My best regards.
Sebastiano

Comment: I suspect you're misinterpreting Werner's answer, and the structure of Stack Exchange. Notwithstanding his skyrocketing reputation, Werner is a user like any other and can't (rather probably) implement any certificate system. Stack Exchange is a company, and those who develop the system feature are the Stack Exchange employees. You can make this a feature request _ai piani alti_ but I don't think that it would be considered with high priority.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano, perhaps I have not explained well. I did not ask Werner a certificate rather, saw his long experience TeX.SE etc., if he had a contact with the site owners and request them to endorse my cause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange keeps track of the *day*s you were active on the site, but not the separate hours. So you won't be able to see how long you have been active, but you will be able to see the days on which you logged in.

To view this, click on the "calendar" in the bottom-right of your profile page.

[image]

You can scroll back and identify the days where you were active on the site (in UTC).

Perhaps, it would be possible to extract content from the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) in terms of your activity. That is, extract the times of your posts (questions and answers) as well as comments and estimate the time you spend on the site. However, an exact duration of active involvement would not be possible. For Stack Exchange to keep that amount of information on every user would probably be prohibitive.

Comment: Very kind Werner where is it possible to extract content from the SEDE in terms of my activity? I not find it. Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano: If by "activity" you're referring to you being on the site (similar to what is displayed in the "calendar" area under your profile page, then that's not available in SEDE. They don't store information about page views or site visits by individual.

Comment: Kindest Werner I remember that there is also a plot of a graph of my activities. Thank you so much for your comment. Thank again.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I'd suggest looking at [queries on SEDE related to "user activity"](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries?order_by=popular&q=user+activity). For example, this one: [User activity, with totally unnecessary bells and whistles](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/678212/user-activity-with-totally-unnecessary-bells-and-whistles)

Comment: Kindest Werner I think to have understood the mechanicism of the site. My English is not very good :-(((( Thank you always very much. Approved you! :)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding just a little on @Werner 's answer:

> Perhaps, it would be possible to extract content from the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) in
>   terms of your activity.

That would require a little database programming. Perhaps you could find a user (not a stackexchange administrator) to do that by asking at https://stackoverflow.com/ . You wouldn't be able to show what you'd done on your own to answer the question except point to this discussion, but maybe someone would be challenged to help.

Comment: Thank you too for your kind response. I do not know what type of database programming may be required. You could submit it for me my request? I thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't submit your request, but you can. Ask at stackoverflow, with a link to your question here.