# Graphs on the duration of access to the TeX.SE site for professional training

Tags: discussion, statistics, request-for-information

In a previous question [A clock into StackExchange to access time counting](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7170/a-clock-into-stackexchange-to-access-time-counting), given the numerous frequent changes and updates by the operators of the site I would like to know if there is a possibility of a time chart for a given period being printed.

It is important to me to motivate my professional development. A few months ago I saw some graphs in one of the many questions/answers asked by a user. At the moment I don't remember where it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/975273?UserId=117876#graph) that highlights the unique days you were active on TeX.SE and counting the number of actions (votes, posts, suggested edit reviews and comments) you performed (that's public):

[image]

To some extent, it echoes [your reputation graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano?tab=reputation):

[image]

This is to be expected since most reputation is earned within a short period of being active (posting content).

Comment: You can add his network graph profile  https://stackexchange.com/users/9574961/sebastiano?tab=reputation

Comment: @AndréC Hi, yes I have seen the link of my network graph profile. Thank you, but it is not very exhaustive for my opinion.

Comment: @Werner Two questions: 1) I would to undestand well (all the explanations) of 1st graph in detail. It is now not clear. Among the tabs of the link https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/975273?UserId=117876#graph I have found very interesting the tab Results. It is have a file .xls (Download CSV) where I can stamp the file. But why into the date I have always 00:00:00?

Comment: @Werner Why isn't the duration of access reported? What is the explanation of Action_Cnt where I have only numbers? Finally, where can I get the last two charts? I ask you if possible to edit your excellent answer in relation to my comments that I will later delete.

Comment: @Sebastiano: In [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/975273?UserId=117876) I extract only the year/month/day and remove the timestamp because some data (like the timestamp of a vote) is always `00:00:00`. So, essentially, the query (1) extracts the date and timestamp of all actions you've performed, then (2) removes the time-stamp and (3) tallies/counts the actions to come up with a count by day.

Comment: @Sebastiano: The duration is not available because it will most likely be such a large amount of information to keep track of (for very little value). You can see your own "*days* active on the site" by clicking on the [calendar/visited days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUdDR.png) portion of [your profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano). That information is private and only visible by you.

Comment: @Werner Very interesting calendar/visited days because I see the green cells when I have logged into TeX.SE. I have upvoted you and accept it. Thank you always very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Yes, that "calendar/visited days" is just a toggle to show you were on the site an that day. That is tracked regardless of whether you perform any other action. Just logging in/browsing on that day and it's captured. My answer provides a chart for some activities other than just logging in/browsing.