# A clock for time travel

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

This morning I have seen a clock for time travel in the toolbar at the top right

[image]

and many colored stars with the font Comics Sans (under construction Big changes for Y2K). What do you mean?

[image]

Someone knows if they've finally put on a watch that marks the time of access. See one of my old questions
[A clock into StackExchange to access time counting](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7170/a-clock-into-stackexchange-to-access-time-counting)

Comment: I think everybody is wondering the same thing :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Everything moves here, LOL :-) I hope they don't change everything again. I don't like those blue colors when we enter the code.

Comment: Everybody don't like them :)

Comment: I don't see ComicSans, maybe my system tries to keep me safe!

Comment: @Skillmon Look the title of my 1st image and of this link https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typefaces/story-of-comic-sans

Comment: @Sebastiano don't worry, I know what ComicSans is, but there is none on my PC, so Firefox selects another hand-writing font as substitution, but that one does look decent :)

Comment: @Sebastiano and I can only see that other font on other sites of the network, on TeX.SX I fixed my fonts using userCSS because I didn't like the one they used after they changed the page's layout.

Comment: @Skillmon Don't worry. You and many users are welcome for any comment and question. My best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're celebrating April 1: it's already new day [in the Pacific](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/kiribati/kiritimati).

Comment: Good guess.  I hope it goes away soon.  I have problems reading the text when brightly colored moving spots keep obscuring it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You can click on the clock icon in the top-right corner of this page to disable the joke!

Comment: Hence it is the 20th anniversary of the start of StackExchange.

Comment: @user49915 Absolutely no :-) It is right. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's actually the 10th anniversary, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine. Of course it was on purpose to do this kind of anniversary celebration on April 1st.

Comment: @user49915 yes, so the way I understand it is that the April Fools joke this year has a retro theme because of the 10th anniversary. So it is part of the anniversary celebrations, or a combination of the anniversary and April Fools - in any case the anniversary has something to do with it :)